# Pass form values to another function without submitting

Tags: javascript, php, post, yii, get

My goal is:
I have an `/edit` action in my Yii project containing some form with fields let's say:`text`, `image`.
There are some values entered to these forms (let's say 'my text' and 'my image').

I have a button Save (we don't use it) and a button which directs me to action `/preview`, and I need to pass there an array like `['text' => 'my text', 'image' => 'my image']` or the same as an object.

Can I even do this without submitting the form? I thought about javascript, but is there some way to avoid using it?

Comment: You could do this with an ajax request and call an insertion script periodically when a certain action was perform

Comment: there is no way you can get the data of the form without submitting if you don't want to use ajax...or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, using Javascript ( jQuery + AJAX ) is the way to do it, and I don't think there is another way.

Comment: Okay, thanks. One more thing: can I pass files like this? My form saves files on submit, but can I also send somehow information from $_FILES?

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form to either /edit or /preview, depending on which button is clicked.

It's a pity you didn't take the time to show your form code. However, assuming your form looks like

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="submit"  data-url="/edit"  value="Edit" />
    <input type="submit" data-url="/preview" value="Preview" />
    ...
</form>
```

You can submit the form to one or the other.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#my_form").submit(function( event )
     var url = $(this).attr('data-url');

     $('#my_form').attr('action',url);   
          :
    });
});
```